# How to make a delay in React

Tags: reactjs, delay, use-reducer

When you click on the button, another screen is rendered:

```
<button className="button _button_two_column" onClick={()=> dispatch({type: "NEXT_SCREEN"})}>
```

```
if (action.type === 'NEXT_SCREEN') {
        return {
            ...state,
            currentScreenIndex: state.currentScreenIndex + 1,
        }
    }
```

/*when 1 is added to the currentScreenIndex the screen changes*/

I need screen 1 to open for 3 seconds when I press the button and then screen 2
How to do it? I tried to do it using setTimeout, but nothing happened

Comment: So, let me get this right: you are on screen 1 when you press the button you will be redirected to the next screen (screen 2) which will stay open for 3 seconds, and then you will be redirected to screen 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook. You can do the `dispatch` inside the callback of `setInterval`. You need to carefully handle the memory leaks as well.

Try like this:

1. Add the following hooks to your component. `trigger` is to trigger the screen transitions. We call `setInterval` only once (using if check) to avoid memory leaks and clear it when the component unmounts.

```
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (trigger) {
      interval = setInterval(() => dispatch({ type: "NEXT_SCREEN" }), 3000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [trigger]);
```

2. Change the trigger to true when the button click happens

```
<button
  className="button _button_two_column"
  onClick={() => setTrigger(true)}
></button>
```

Demo code:

[image: Edit priceless-wu-ulodn1]

Comment: Your answer makes the transition to the next screen after 3 seconds after pressing the button, and I need that when you press the button, the screen opens for 3 seconds and then the next one opens.

Comment: Do you want to automatically transition to the next screens with the same delay after the initial trigger by button click?

Comment: That's right. I'm sorry, I use a translator, so I might not put it that way.

Comment: Yes I use useReducer

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, your answer never came up to my task, but I changed your answer and it turned out the way I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use setTimeout() function to make a delay.
And avoid to use javascript function in html.

```
const onClick = () => {
    setTimeout(dispatch({type: "NEXT_SCREEN"}), 1000)
}
<button className="button _button_two_column" onClick={onClick}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my task:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let interval;
  if (stateScreen.currentScreenIndex===4) {
    interval = setInterval(() => dispatch({ type: "NEXT_SCREEN" }), 2000);
  }
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, );
```